# Bash Script Regular Expressions...How to find and replace all matches?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, search, replace

I am writing a bash script that reads a file line by line.

The file is a .csv file which contains many dates in the format DD/MM/YYYY but I would like to change them to YYYY-MM-DD.

I would to match the data using a regular expression, and replace it such that all of the dates in the file are correctly formatted as YYYY-MM-DD.

I believe this regular expression would match the dates:

```
([0-9][0-9]?)/([0-9][0-9]?)/([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])
```

But I do not know how to find regex matches and replace them with the new format, or if this is even possible in a bash script. Please help!

Answer (score 26):

Try this using sed:

```
line='Today is 10/12/2010 and yesterday was 9/11/2010'
echo "$line" | sed -r 's#([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{4})#\3-\2-\1#g'

OUTPUT:
Today is 2010-12-10 and yesterday was 2010-11-9
```

PS: On mac use `sed -E` instead of `sed -r`

Answer (score 17):

Pure Bash.

```
infile='data.csv'

while read line ; do
  if [[ $line =~ ^(.*),([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{4}),(.*)$ ]] ; then
    echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]},${BASH_REMATCH[4]}-${BASH_REMATCH[3]}-${BASH_REMATCH[2]},${BASH_REMATCH[5]}"
  else
    echo "$line"
  fi
done < "$infile"
```

The input file

```
xxxxxxxxx,11/03/2011,yyyyyyyyyyyyy          
xxxxxxxxx,10/04/2011,yyyyyyyyyyyyy          
xxxxxxxxx,10/05/2012,yyyyyyyyyyyyy          
xxxxxxxxx,10/06/2011,yyyyyyyyyyyyy
```

gives the following output:

```
xxxxxxxxx,2011-03-11,yyyyyyyyyyyyy
xxxxxxxxx,2011-04-10,yyyyyyyyyyyyy
xxxxxxxxx,2012-05-10,yyyyyyyyyyyyy
xxxxxxxxx,2011-06-10,yyyyyyyyyyyyy
```

Comment: Note: some editor suggests to exchange `BASH_REMATCH[2]` and `BASH_REMATCH[3]`.

Comment: I have created a file with `Today is 10/12/2010 and yesterday was 9/11/2010` line 1024138 times (file size ~50 MB) and run your script with redirection of echo commands to the output file, and it took 2 min 20 seconds to complete. While the similar sed command from the answer above, `sed -r 's#([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{4})#\3-\2-\1#g' input_file > output_file`, took just 8 seconds..

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using `sed`

```
echo "11/12/2011" | sed -E 's/([0-9][0-9]?)\/([0-9][0-9]?)\/([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])/\3-\2-\1/'
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't wanna echo...I want to store the result in a new variable

to do that (and i know this isn't exacting to your setup, but still applies in how to use a regex):

```
path="/entertainment/Pictures"
files=(
  "$path"/*.jpg"
  "$path"/*.bmp"
)

for i in "${files[@]}"
do
  # replace jpg and bmp with png in prep for conversion
  new=$(echo "$i" | perl -pe "s/\.jpg|\.bmp/.png")

  # next is to perform the conversion
  ...
done
```

Comment: files=("$path"/*.jpg"
      "$path"/*.bmp"
    )
Are the strings above correctly specified.
Further, this is not what exactly the question asks.

Comment: If you read my post properly you will see I have qualified that my response isn't exact.  Thank you for pointing it out though.

With that said, however, the data is irrelevant. The question is essentially asking how to replace text within a string to something else, which my code demonstrates quite clearly and effectively answers the question

Comment: The question was about regular expression based substitution using bash. You have done it by means of an external program which not every body is  likely to have these days in their systems . Why not use  `sed` instead?  See the response by `Fritz G Mehner`.