# Regex to remove a reoccuring paragraph from text file

Tags: regex

I wrote an expect script to login to a few routes and run `sh inv` command, but the output also
contains the below:

```
********************************* Access Warning!! ***********************************
*                                                                                    *
* This computer system, its network and data contained therein is the property of    *
* the <Company name>. Access to this computer and network is restricted              *
* to persons and programs authorised by the Group only. Access by others is          *
* prohibited and unauthorised, and is wrongful under law. Do not proceed if you      *
* are not authorised. Any unauthorised access will be prosecuted to the fullest      *
* extent of the law.                                                                 *
*                                                                                    *
**************************************************************************************
```

Is there a RegEx that I can use to remove the above re-occuring paragraph from the text file?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: What laws are you breaking?

Comment: I am using Shell Script/bash

Answer (score 0):

It seems from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13043397/2081889) that you could use the Linux command `sed`.

From there, the above text can be matched with the regex:

```
\*{33} Access Warning!! \*{35}.*\*{86}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]