# Why does this regexp matches to almost everything?

Tags: regex, bash

I cant really explain but check out the following:

```
name=$1
pat="\b[0-9a-zA-Z_]+\b"

if [[ $name =~ $pat ]]; then
  echo "$name is ok as user name"
else
  echo "$name is not ok as user name"
  exit 1
fi
```

Test run:

```
./script test_user+
test_user+ is ok as user name
```

The username with a + sign should not match that regexp.

Comment: Why so many downvotes on this question?

Comment: btw [your script works fine](http://ideone.com/nzagNv) **without any change**

Comment: I am curious to the amount of downvotes as well. It is a good question.

Comment: @anubhava: It doesn't here in my testing. It says a username with a `+` is OK, which is not desired behavior. `bash 4.3.42(1)-release` Perhaps it depends on the version?

Comment: It doesnt work on my system though :( I don't know why down votes, we should raise the down votes bar probably as on HackerNews.

Comment: @Istvan: What is your OS? `\b` works on Linux

Comment: @anubhava You are supplying the user name on standard input, which the script ignores, not as an argument.

Comment: I posted an answer below to show that `\b` actually works on Ubuntu and other systems as word boundary

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all:

> `\b` is a PCRE extension; it isn't available in ERE, which the `=~`
>   operator in bash's `[[ ]]` syntax uses.

(From [Bash regex match with word boundary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27476347/bash-regex-match-with-word-boundary))

Second, you don't want word boundaries (`\b`) if you wish to force the entire string to match. You want to match the start (`^`) and end (`$`):

```
pat="^[0-9a-zA-Z_]+\$"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, indeed this is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want word bondry (guessed as you are trying username match) please use

```
^[0-9a-zA-Z_]+$
```

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to the OP's experience and other answer it seems `\b` is supported on `Ubuntu 14.04, bash 4.3.11` as **word boundary**. Here is a sample:

```
re='\bb[0-9]+\b'

[[ 'b123' =~ $re ]] && echo "matched" || echo "nope"
matched

[[ 'b123_' =~ $re ]] && echo "matched" || echo "nope"
nope
```

Even `\<` and `\>` also work fine as word boundaries:

```
re='\<b[0-9]+\>'

[[ 'b123' =~ $re ]] && echo "matched" || echo "nope"
matched

[[ 'b123_' =~ $re ]] && echo "matched" || echo "nope"
nope
```

However support of `\b` is specific to certain OS only. e.g. on OSX following works as word boundary:

```
[[ 'b123' =~ [[:\<:]]b[0-9]+[[:\>:]] ]] && echo "matched" || echo "nope"
matched

[[ 'b123_' =~ [[:\<:]]b[0-9]+[[:\>:]] ]] && echo "matched" || echo "nope"
nope
```