# Removing chars after second space

Tags: regex, bash

Assume that I have this text:

```
eskitirim eski[Verb]-t[Verb+Caus]+[Pos]+Hr[Aor]+YHm[A1sg] : 20.4453125 eski[Verb]-t[Verb+Caus]+[Pos]+Hr[Aor]+Hm[A1sg] : 21.7978515625
```

I want to remove everything after the second space. Output should be:

```
eskitirim eski[Verb]-t[Verb+Caus]+[Pos]+Hr[Aor]+YHm[A1sg]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are absolutely certain that the format (as to spacing) will always be exactly as you've shown it in the question, a simpler solution might be appropriate, but I would dig deeper into the semantics of your data to give a more robust solution.

1) If spacing could possibly vary but you definitely want only the first two non-space-containing sequences, use `awk '{print $1,$2}'`.

2) If the `:` is significant and guaranteed to be present, I would use that rather than spaces to delimit what you are after: `awk -F: '{print $1}'`.

3) I would not recommend any `sed`/regex solution unless there can be more than one sequential space *and* it is critical to preserve the exact amount of such space.

Comment: no result with this try: cat parse.txt | awk -F: '{print $1}' > out1.txt

Comment: It's working for me: `$ cat out1.txt`-->`eskitirim eski[Verb]-t[Verb+Caus]+[Pos]+Hr[Aor]+YHm[A1sg]`

Comment: I'm using osx. maybe I should try under Linux?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a capturing group to capture everything before the second space:

```
(.*?\s.*?)\s.*
```

And then replace everything with the first capturing group match.

[**Example Here**](https://regex101.com/r/kT0dN1/1)

So `(.*?\s.*?)\s.*` replaced with `\1` would output:

```
eskitirim eski[Verb]-t[Verb+Caus]+[Pos]+Hr[Aor]+YHm[A1sg]
```

Alternatively, you could also replace `.` with `\S`:

```
(\S*\s\S*)\s.*
```

[**Same output**](https://regex101.com/r/yH2aV0/1).

Comment: @JayGatsby See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13043344/search-and-replace-in-bash-using-regular-expressions

Comment: @JayGatsby `echo $string | sed 's/\(\S*\s\S*\)\s.*/\1/g'` worked for me.

Comment: @JoshCrozier: ``echo $string | sed -r 's/^(\S+\s\S+)\s.*/\1/'``: the ``-r`` switch enable ERE (brackets and plus doesn't need escaping) and there is no reason to use the global ``g`` flag

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a simple `cut` to do the job:

```
~$ echo 'eskitirim ... ' | cut -d' ' -f-2        # or -f1,2
# eskitirim eski[Verb]-t[Verb+Caus]+[Pos]+Hr[Aor]+YHm[A1sg]

~$ echo 'eskitirim ... ' | cut -d':' -f1
# eskitirim eski[Verb]-t[Verb+Caus]+[Pos]+Hr[Aor]+YHm[A1sg]
```