# how to remove last comma from line in bash using "sed or awk"

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Hi I want to remove last comma from a line. For example:

Input:

```
This,is,a,test
```

Desired Output:

```
This,is,a test
```

I am able to remove last comma if its also the last character of the string using below command: (However this is not I want)

```
echo "This,is,a,test," |sed 's/,$//'
This,is,a,test
```

Same command does not work if there are more characters past last comma in line.

```
echo "This,is,a,test" |sed 's/,$//'
This,is,a,test
```

I am able to achieve the results using dirty way by calling multiple commands, any  alternative to achieve the same using awk or sed regex  ?(This is I want)

```
echo "This,is,a,test" |rev |sed 's/,/ /' |rev
This,is,a test
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search and replace in bash using regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13043344/search-and-replace-in-bash-using-regular-expressions)

Comment: There is no need to spawn a sed, awk, etc. process, since a pure Bash solution exists: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22261454/1671066

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```bash
$ echo "This,is,a,test" | sed 's/\(.*\),/\1 /'
This,is,a test

$ echo "This,is,a,test" | perl -pe 's/.*\K,/ /'
This,is,a test
```

In both cases, `.*` will match as much as possible, so only the last comma will be changed.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a regex that matches not-comma, and captures that group, and then restores it in the replacement.

```
echo "This,is,a,test" |sed 's/,\([^,]*\)$/ \1/'
```

Output:

```
This,is,a test
```

Answer (score 5):

All the answer are based on regex. Here is a non-regex way to remove last comma:

```
s='This,is,a,test'
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {$(NF-1)=$(NF-1) " " $NF; NF--} 1' <<< "$s"

This,is,a test
```

Answer (score 2):

In Gnu AWK too since tagged:

```
$ echo This,is,a,test|awk '$0=gensub(/^(.*),/,"\\1 ","g",$0)'
This,is,a test
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is by using [Bash Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

```
$ s="This,is,a,test"
$ echo "${s%,*} ${s##*,}"
This,is,a test
```