# regexp doesn't work in pattern substitution word expansion

Tags: regex, bash

I have followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13043344/search-and-replace-in-bash-using-regular-expressions) to implement the bash regex

```
#!/bin/bash
MYVAR=ho02123ware38384you443d34o3434ingtod38384day
MYVAR=${MYVAR//[[:alpha:]]/X} 
echo ${MYVAR//[[:digit:]]/N}
```

However, when I try with a more **complex regex**, it doesn't replace anything:

```
#!/bin/bash
PREVIOUS_CONFIGURATION=`cat /etc/apache2/sites-available/user-domain.conf`
NEW_CONFIGURATION=${PREVIOUS_CONFIGURATION//ServerName .+?\n/testbro} 
echo "$NEW_CONFIGURATION"
exit 1
```

This is how my file `user-domain.conf` looks like:

```
        ServerName CUSTOM_USER_DOMAIN
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /home/sifoo2/server2.wassap.io

        <Directory /home/sifoo2/server2.wassap.io/>
```

Comment: what do you want the result to look like?

Comment: Since you're reading from a file into a variable, can you accept `NEW_CONFIGURATION=$(sed -E "s/ServerName .+$/testbro/" user-domain.conf)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern used in a pattern substitution word expansion is not a regular expression, but a glob, or an extended glob if `extglob` option is enabled. As a glob, `.+?` matches `.+` and any single character following that; `.+a`, `.+1`, etc.

Your aim here is apparently performing a non-greedy/lazy/reluctant match but that's not possible with normal globs. However a workaround with extended globs is available (shortened variable names for better readability):

```
shopt -s extglob
new=${prev//ServerName +([!$'\n'])/testbro}
```

See:

- [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#index-expansion_002c-parameter)
- [Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching)

Comment: Thank you this worked! You definitely know your stuff :)

Answer (score -2):

Try it like this:

```
${var//ServerName\ [[:alpha:]]*/testbro}
```